# PHP MYSQL Display results including NULL with Case statements

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, case

I can't get the clients to show when no data is in the LEFT JOINED TABLE. I think it is due to my CASE statements. I've tried every way I can think of. Thanks in advance for the help.
Current Results show all Clients with Onsite_Hours or Remote_Hours if they have Hours listed. The issue is, I have Clients that have Onsite_Hours or Remote_Hours that do not display because there aren't any Hours table entries.

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
    Clients.Id,
    Clients.Rate,
    Clients.Name,
    Clients.onsite_block_hrs,
    Clients.remote_block_hrs,
    Clients.Net,
    SUM(case WHEN Clients.onsite_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS Onsite_Hours,
    SUM(case WHEN Clients.remote_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS Remote_Hours,
    SUM(case WHEN DAY(Hours.Date) <= 15 && Clients.onsite_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS First_Hours,
    SUM(case WHEN DAY(Hours.Date) >= 16 && Clients.onsite_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS Second_Hours,
    Hours.Customer,
    Hours.Date
FROM
    Clients
LEFT JOIN
    Hours ON Clients.Id=Hours.Customer
WHERE
    MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND (onsite_block_hrs != 0 || remote_block_hrs != 0)
    GROUP BY Id
    ORDER BY Name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
```

Adding Sample data and expected results:

TABLE Clients

```
Id | Name   |  onsite_block_hrs  | remote_block_hrs
1  | Test1  |  3                  | 0
2  | Test2  |  0                  | 1
3  | Test3  |  0                  | 2
4  | Test4  | 3                   | 0
5  | Test5  | 0                   | 0
```

TABLE Hours

```
Id | Customer | Date       | Hours
1  | 1        | 1-Jan-2018 | 2
2  | 2        | 2-Feb-2018 | 2
3  | 3        | 5-Feb-2018 | 1
4  | 5        | 3-Feb-2018 | 5
```

Expected Output:
Client 1 Display because They have 3 onsite hours and 2 hours but dont show hours because they aren't during the current month
Client 2 Display because they have 1 remote and 2 hours in current month
Client 3 Display Same Reason
Client 4 Display because they have 3 Onsite hours even though no record in Hours
Client 5 Don't display because there are no onsite or remote hours

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: I've read the article. I'm sorry, but not sure I see what I am missing. I've included the only pertinent code, and explained what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well let's try this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: When editing look at the formatted version below the edit box. Click on 'edited' to see how I corrected your block code table format & list format (2 spaces at line end). We should be able to cut & paste & run a [mcve]. (That includes formatting tables also as code to set/input tables.) Give expected output as a table. (Ideally as table-formatted code whose sorted output we can diff to our output.)

Comment: (Updated comment.) Find out what left join on does. It returns inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. So all left table rows always appear in output. When you left join on *always* know what its associated right join on is. And a where that requires right table columns to be non-null removes any rows that left join on returned more than inner join on would have, so one should have used inner join to be clear. You are doing that kind of pointless left join here.

Comment: PS Note that ensuring a [mcve] is minimal typically involves finding code that gets you part way that doesn't have a problem then adding something. Likely this would have shown that your left join on is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Date comes from the Hours table; including field from the right table of a LEFT JOIN in the WHERE clause can effectively turn it into an INNER JOIN if NULL values are not allowed; it is more likely you need to move those criteria into the join condition, something like:

```
...
LEFT JOIN Hours ON Clients.Id=Hours.Customer
AND (MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))
WHERE (onsite_block_hrs != 0 || remote_block_hrs != 0)
...
```

However, the OR part probably makes the actual solution a little less obvious, and should have resulted in some records being returned.\

In fact, the OR conditions on onsite_block_hours and remote_block_hrs, should have produced results summing all Hours (ignoring the date range completely...unless they had none.)

Comment: Uueerdo, This solution worked! thank you for the help. I don't have the rank to upvote, but this is the correct solution.

Comment: @kayakerpaul You can click on the check mark icon to show this helped most & to award rep.

Comment: Just did. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your example:

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
    Clients.Id,
    Clients.Rate,
    Clients.Name,
    Clients.onsite_block_hrs,
    Clients.remote_block_hrs,
    Clients.Net,
    SUM(case WHEN Clients.onsite_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS Onsite_Hours,
    SUM(case WHEN Clients.remote_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS Remote_Hours,
    SUM(case WHEN DAY(Hours.Date) <= 15 && Clients.onsite_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS First_Hours,
    SUM(case WHEN DAY(Hours.Date) >= 16 && Clients.onsite_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS Second_Hours,
    Hours.Customer,
    Hours.Date
FROM
    Clients
LEFT JOIN
    Hours ON Clients.Id=Hours.Customer
WHERE
    (MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) OR (onsite_block_hrs != 0 || remote_block_hrs != 0)
    GROUP BY Id
    ORDER BY Name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
```

So that you retrieve clients with either Hours from current Date **OR** (not AND, as in your example) with onsite_block_hrs/remote_block_hrs greater than 0 - this is what you are looking for if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Your solution would show all Hours entries regardless of the Date requirements. I need the Date on the Hours record to be during the current month, AND the Client has to have onsite_block_hrs OR remote_block_hrs, but If they have block_hrs and no Hours entries, still display.

Answer (score 0):

From Uueerdo. this is the final solution:

I moved the Month and Year requirements to the JOIN.

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
Clients.Id,
Clients.Rate,
Clients.Name,
Clients.onsite_block_hrs,
Clients.remote_block_hrs,
Clients.Net,
SUM(case WHEN Clients.onsite_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS Onsite_Hours,
SUM(case WHEN Clients.remote_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS Remote_Hours,
SUM(case WHEN DAY(Hours.Date) <= 15 && Clients.onsite_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS First_Hours,
SUM(case WHEN DAY(Hours.Date) >= 16 && Clients.onsite_block_hrs > 0 then Hours.Hours else 0 end) AS Second_Hours,
Hours.Customer,
Hours.Date
FROM
Clients
LEFT JOIN
Hours ON Clients.Id=Hours.Customer
AND (MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(Date) = 
YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))
WHERE
(onsite_block_hrs != 0 || remote_block_hrs != 0)
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY Name";
```